# In Fortran, are there type-agnostic data containers that avoid allocations?

Tags: generics, data-structures, casting, fortran

In C, one can use `void *` together with a size and pointer casts to describe build type-agnostic interfaces and data structures. For example:

```
// generic sort function
void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t item_size,
           int (*compare)(const void *, const void*));

// generic linked list node
struct list_node {
    struct list_node *next;
    void *payload;
};
```

In Fortran, we can mimic this by using an `character` (byte) array:

```
subroutine qsort(base, compare)
    character, contiguous, intent(inout) :: base(:, :)
    interface
        pure integer function compare(x, y)
            character, contiguous, intent(in) :: x(:), y(:)                   
        end
    end interface
end

type :: list_node
    type(list_node), pointer :: next
    character, allocatable :: payload(:)
end type
```

together with the Fortran 90 [`TRANSFER` intrinsic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TRANSFER.html), which is Fortran's version of
"casting". However, there is a catch: as far as I understand, unlike a true "cast",
TRANSFER will always allocate a new array and copy the contents into that array.

So here is the question: is there a way to do this without the copying overhead?

Answer (score 2):

With "pure Fortran" you cannot. But you can use the (standard) C interoperability features to take advantage of C flexibility:

Edit: following @Francescalus comments about the conformity to the standard I have modified the proposed solution. The idea is rather to use the `c_ptr` type to carry the payload: this is actually simpler, and quite close to what would be done in C (`c_ptr` is after all the Fortran side for a `void*` pointer)

```
use iso_c_binding

!character, allocatable, target :: payload(:) 
!integer, pointer :: actualdata(:)
!call c_f_pointer(c_loc(payload),actualdata,[n]) 
!! n is the number of integer elements 
!! you have previously put into payload(:)

type(c_ptr) :: payload

! In in calling program, "put" the data into the payload
integer, allocatable, target :: originaldata(:)
payload = c_loc(originaldata)

! In the library, "get" the data from the payload
integer, pointer :: dataptr(:)
call c_f_pointer(payload,dataptr,[n])
```

Comment: Except that this isn't valid Fortran...

Comment: @francescalus maybe you're right, but could you elaborate more?

Comment: Because it tries to pointer associate an integer pointer with a character target.

Comment: @francescalus Indeed, this is precisely the objective... Both ifort and gfortran compile such code without any warning, even when enforcing strict standard conformance.

Comment: I'm sure they both compile the "program" `print *, x; end` but this is still not valid Fortran. For your example, `c_f_pointer` has three cases, depending on what the `cptr` argument is. The third case clearly doesn't apply here, leaving the choice depending on whether default character is interoperable or not. The interoperable case requires the Fortran and C entities to be interoperable (they aren't); the non-interoperable case requires the type and type parameters of the two Fortran entities to be the same (they aren't).

Comment: As I understand it, using `integer(c_char)` instead of `character` would do?

Comment: Do you mean `integer(c_signed_char)`? (Even if `c_char` is positive, it's not necessarily an integer kind parameter.) That's still not "type-agnostic", in that you'd still be able to point to the target only from integers of the same kind. Use of `call c_f_pointer(c_loc(x), fptr)` is defined by the Fortran standard to be equivalent to `fptr =>x` (when that pointer assignment is allowed). It's not a magic way of allowing type punning.

Comment: `integer(c_signed_char)`, yes... These restrictions on `c_f_pointer` weren't exactly clear to me until now (and I'm still not sure how bad it could be in this context). Anyway, what about "packing" the payload into a simple `c_ptr`? This would actually be simpler, (hopefully) conformant, and closer to what would be done directly in C.

Comment: What makes the `type(c_ptr)` version allowed is that `originaldata` and `dataptr` have the same type and type parameter. (It would be just as not allowed as the first attempt, if they differed in some way.) But given they are the same, this setup seems rather unnecessary, and hardly "type-agnostic". Can you give more detail?

Comment: The OP talked about "type-agnostic" interface and data structure, not about fully "type-agnostic" code